# Stop rails from compiling javascript before running rspec?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, capybara

I have a rails app I'm working on for someone and I"m not sure if this is a problem with a configuration somewhere or something else. It's rails 3, I'm using zeus, the test suite is rspec with capybara webkit, and selenium. Whenever I run a spec locally for the first time (whether through zeus or just normal rspec) it's taking a while to run and will sometimes timeout. When I tail the test logs it's clearly compiling all the javascript files (which are a lot because the project uses angular on the front end). After running it the first time though and letting it compile, the tests run fine after that. Sometimes it compiles again but I haven't figured out that pattern yet.

Is there any way to prevent that initial compilation from happening? I think it's happening when starting a rails server sometimes too because that will be slow to start occasionally. Thanks for any help!

Comment: It will recompile the JS for the test environment whenever there has been a change in the JS - you don't want to disable that, or your tests won't be running with the latest JS code, it's the rails asset pipeline doing its job

Comment: Are there any ways to speed that up?

Comment: not really - although you can run it yourself first to stop it from timing out during a test run -   RAILS_ENV=test rake assets:precompile

Comment: It's not consistently every time I change a js file though.

Comment: it should be, but you may not notice it, some files being changed cause much less change than others, the asset pipeline caches a bunch of compiled files and tries to only "recompile" the exact ones that change and then those affected by that change too, so if you make a small change in a file that isn't depended on by anything else it won't generate much work

Comment: Is there any way to configure or debug those dependencies? The behavior I'm seeing is definitely not what's supposed to be happening. It's usually all js is compiled or none.

Comment: You can read about the asset pipeline in the docs -- http://guides.rubyonrails.org/v3.2/asset_pipeline.html  -- it talks about dependencies, etc.